# Consume ReadLine method in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, stopwatch

I have a program that takes input: The first line read is the number of coordinates that will be given, the rest of the lines are the coordinates themselves. It reads all coordinates and finds the shortest distance between any two points(The distance between the two closest coordinates) and then displays the distance and the time it took to find the answer.

My problem is that when I run the program, I have to hit the **Enter** key in order for the "time it took to find the answer" to calculate. I have to use input data of 1000 integers so I have to **Paste** the numbers into the console - then immediately hit enter so that too much time does not elapse.

My question is: What is the simplest way to consume the ReadLine method so that the program's `Stopwatch` object does not have to wait for the **Enter** key to be pressed. I cannot figure this problem out.

Here is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double smallestDistance = 0.0;
            int numberOfPoints = 0;
            String userInput = "";
            String coordinate = "";
            int coordinatesEntered = 0;

            //Grab the number of points that will be used.
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            //Try and convert and store the input to an integer.
            numberOfPoints = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);

            int[] xcoords = new int[numberOfPoints];
            int[] ycoords = new int[numberOfPoints];

            //Create a new stopwatch in order to time program.
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            //Get all the points.
            while(coordinatesEntered < numberOfPoints)
            {   
                coordinate = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] numbers = coordinate.Split(' ');

                xcoords[coordinatesEntered] = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]);
                ycoords[coordinatesEntered] = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[1]);

                coordinatesEntered++;
            }//end while

            smallestDistance = getShortestDistance(xcoords, ycoords, numberOfPoints);
            sw.Stop ( );
            Console.Write ("\n");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N6}", Math.Sqrt(smallestDistance)));
            Console.WriteLine ("Time used: {0} secs", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 1000);
            Console.ReadKey ( );
        }

        public static double getShortestDistance(int[] x, int[] y, int numOfCoords)
        {
            int i;
            int j;

            double shortestDistance = 0;

            for (i = 0; i<numOfCoords-1 ; i++)
            {
                for (j= i+1 ; j<numOfCoords ; j++)
                {
                    double xresultsqrd = Math.Pow((x[j] - x[i]), 2.0);
                    double yresultsqrd = Math.Pow((y[j] - y[i]), 2.0);

                    double finalResult = xresultsqrd + yresultsqrd;

                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        shortestDistance = finalResult;
                    }else if(finalResult < shortestDistance){
                        shortestDistance = finalResult;
                    }//end elseif
                }//end inner-for
            }//end outer-for

            return shortestDistance;
        }//end getShortestDistance;

    }//end class Program
}//end namespace ConsoleApplication2
```

Here is the txt file needed for input:
http://hastebin.com/zulowuvuyu.lisp

I believe the problem is that the `ReadLine` method is waiting for **Enter** to be pressed, but since I am **Pasting** No Enter key is ever read. How can I cause the ReadLine to stop looking for an Enter to be pressed(aka consume the method)?

Comment: Are you trying to measure the time it takes to input the coordinates? Or just the time it takes to do the calculation?

Comment: Also, if the data is already in a file (you are copying from somewhere), why not just read the file?

Comment: best thing is to read your input from a file as @Rufus L mentioned

Comment: I am trying to do the time it takes to perform the calculation. I am actually required to enter the text manually therefore I cannot use StreamReader

Comment: Why don't you move the Stopwatch to after your while loop?

Comment: Thank you so much Erik Funkenbusch. That's exactly what I needed to do I just wasn't thinking. Time just went from .77 to .08. That's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but adding an additional carriage return to your input list does the trick.

Better solutions would be to:

- Read it from a different source (like a file)
- Read the input as a stream using `Console.In`

Comment: Better to add as a comment rather than an answer :)

Comment: why? Am I not answering the question? He asked for the simplest solution

Comment: Edited answer seems to be better. Code snippet would also be good.

Comment: I don't see how reading the input as a stream would help. Please elaborate. The stream won't terminate the final line, either with a newline or by reaching the end-of-stream, so it's hard to see how that suggestion would improve things.